# Laravel codeception api testing test structure

Tags: api-testing, php, api, codeception

I want to test all my API endpoints with codeception.

I started off with a more model-based approach:

```php
    class UserCest
    {
        public function it_can_request_its_own_status (ApiTester $I) {
            $user = $I->amLoggedIn();
            $I->sendGET('/users/'.$user->id.'/status');
            $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
            $I->seeResponseContainsJson(['status' => 'active']);
        }
    }
```

Now I realized that I might want to map the test directly to the routes to make it more obvious what route is tested. I thought that this would therefore rather refer to the controller that is used by the routes rather than models:

```php
    class UserControllerCest
    {
        public users__user__status (ApiTester $I) {
            $route = __FUNCTION__;
            $user = $I->amLoggedIn();
            $url = $this->fillRouteWithUserId($route, $user);
            $I->sendGET($url);
            $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
            $I->seeResponseContainsJson(['status' => 'active']);
        }
    }
```

What (other) approach is suitable for testing my API? Maybe to create a separate Cest for every route?